# How would a front-end developer learn some graphic design techniques

Tags: user-interface, frontend

As a front-end developer, I would like to develop nice and good usability web applications. However, normally developers are good at coding. So, I would ask how to get started with learning some UI design knowledge? What's your recommended books or courses for a newbie to learn? Basically for graphic design, fonts and colors etc etc.

Comment: Probably a better question for the UX site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I disagree, UX is not graphic design.

Comment: as much as I like this question, it is sadly off-topic.

Comment: @JHuangweb, true...but, it's a closer match than SO. The OP mentions "nice and good usability" as well as "UI design" which match up better on ux.stackexchange.com and will likely yield better answers. My two cents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a UI/UX developer myself, graphic design techniques are questions related to Photoshop, Illustrator, color theory, typography, etc.  Usability is related to UI/UX, coding and web architecture.  Graphic design and web usability are two very distinctive fields.

**What is User Experience Design?** - [Wiki article on UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design)

> User Experience is any aspect of a person's interaction with a given
> IT system, including the interface, graphics, industrial design,
> physical interaction, and the manual.

**What is graphic Design?** - [Wiki article on Graphic Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_design)

> "Graphic design is the art of communication, stylizing, and
> problem-solving through the use of type and image."

Resources @Nathan provided are great, I would also add this to your reading arsenal, education and inspiration:

## Open University classes

- University of Washington - [Visualization](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse558/05wi/schedule.html)
- MIT - [Drawings & Numbers](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/architecture/4-638-drawings-numbers-five-centuries-of-digital-design-fall-2002/)
- USQ - [Multimedia](http://ocw.usq.edu.au/course/view.php?id=15)
- Berkeley - [Computer Graphics](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs184/fa06/lectures/lectures.html)

## Sites & Inspirations

- [OnePageLove](http://onepagelove.com/)
- [Responsive.ly](http://responsive.ly/)
- [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/)
- [Awwwards](http://www.awwwards.com/)
- [Css Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/)
- [Tuts plus](http://net.tutsplus.com/)
- [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/)

As with any other skill set, to way to get better is practice, practice, practice.  I would just keep building projects as case studies and learn the skill sets as you venture through different types of web applications.

Best of luck on this journey.

Comment: thank you for your information. Honestly to say, currently I have almost zero knowledge of graphics, fonts and colors (I have no idea of how to combine proper shape, color and fonts to compose nice look and feel). That's why I could build a web application but looks bad. So, it is the reason why I want to know some graphics knowledge. And I believe your information will help me a lot on this.

Answer (score 1):

Books are good, but to stay upfront and get aware of what is happening the latest and what tools and techniques are in, I suggest you to actively participate on webistes like

**[Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)**,

**[Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/)** &

**[Web design Ledger](http://webdesignledger.com/)**

to name a few, but top quality resources. To know more about the books, you can refer to

**[Apress Books for front end development](http://www.apress.com/web-development/web-design)**

for start to ninja resources.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Build on the shoulders of those who have gone before.** To be a great developer, you have to know your stuff. In the same way, to be a good designer requires understanding of some basic foundational guidelines. Some of it may seem pretty simple and tedious, but understanding the proper principles of typography, color theory, grid systems and so on can help you a lot. A few resources to get you going are:

   - [*Universal Principles of Design*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592535879)
   - [*The Elements of Typographic Design*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0881792063) by  **Robert Bringhurst**
   - [*Thinking with Type*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568989695) by **Ellen Lupton**
   - [*Grid Systems: Principles of Organizing Type*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568984650) by **Kimberly Elam**
   - [*The Design of Everyday Things*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465067107) by **Donald Norman**
   - [*Don't Make Me Think: A Common Sense Approach to Web Usability*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758) by **Steve Krug**
   - [*Microinteractions: Designing with Details*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491945923) by **Dan Saffer**

   That list should generate it's own follow-on books / websites reading list for you.
2. **Ask questions.** Find some designers you really like and ask questions. Try to understand why they made the decisions they did. Most people are pretty willing to talk about their own work. Asking questions helps you to understand why designers use (or don't use) certain design principles in their work.
3. **Actually design (and seek out constructive criticism.)** Like anything you do in life, reading and learning can only take you so far. At some point, you have to start practicing. Find a small circle / community of more senior designers who can review your designers and give you some brutal, but constructive criticism. Your stuff will suck at first. Everyone's work does. Designers spend hours upon hours honing their talents and skills. Don't get discouraged by it. Just like anything you can gain mastery in, it takes time. Having people in your life who can give constructive feedback is a huge help.

Comment: really appreciate your information and encourages! you really helps me to learn the design concepts with courage!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [WebAwwards](http://www.webawwards.com) never let me down yet... Great selection and new websites added every day